# Node.js not linked error

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I've literally searched everything on web. But I could not find the solution for the error `node-0.8.8 already installed, it's just not linked`. Is it related to a path file issue?

Comment: Can you provide some context to what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've downloaded node 0.5 and trying to update to latest version. I'm using 'brew install node'. It installs the 0.8.8 version but after I type "node --version" it says the older version.

Answer (score 220):

Execute this list of commands in this particular order:

```
sudo brew uninstall node
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew install node
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)
brew link --overwrite node
brew postinstall node
```

Comment: running brew in sudo mode is no longer supported

Answer (score 48):

After you've run `brew upgrade` to update node to the latest version, run `brew doctor` to see what potential problems there are. It might tell you that node is unlinked, in which case, running `brew link node` will link it. (You might need to first run `brew unlink node`)

Comment: I keep getting this error--- Could not symlink include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
/usr/local/include/node is not writable --- any ideas?

Comment: @SleepsOnNewspapers http://developpeers.com/blogs/fix-for-homebrew-permission-denied-issues

Comment: For some reason I need to run "brew update" instead of "brew upgrade"

Comment: Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node

Answer (score 28):

I got the same error today and it told me that Node was not properly linked and there were unexpected header files as well.

When I tried to reinstall node, It told me that it was already installed, just not linked.

```
Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable

/usr/local/bin/node already exists. Remove it
```

### Solution

To fix this, I took ownership of it by using:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/
```

Then I force linked all files by using:

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

After that I did the post install routine with:

```
brew postinstall node
```

Then I checked if node was properly installed with:

```
node -v
```

I received output `v5.1.0` and It was fixed :). Hope this helps.

This may not be the perfect fix out there since I have started dabbling with node and homebrew just 10 minutes ago but it did the job for me.

Answer (score 6):

Your old version of Node 0.5 was probably not installed with Homebrew (or Homebrew's script changed in the large gap between the 0.5 beta releases to the 0.8 stable releases (the 0.6 and 0.7 releases in-between).

Both Homebrew and the official Node installer try to install to `/usr/local/bin` so I'd recommend starting by simply deleting `/usr/local/bin/node`, `/usr/local/bin/npm`, and `/usr/local/lib/node` and try again.

Comment: You should delete modules also. `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

Answer (score 3):

hardcorepunk's answer worked. However, we can no longer chown `/usr/local` in High Sierra. So, execute the commands in this order:

```
sudo brew uninstall node
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew install node
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
brew link --overwrite node
brew postinstall node
```

Answer (score 1):

To link the node, run following command:

```
brew link homebrew/versions/node<version no>
```

And to check whether it is properly installed or not, run:

```
node -v
```

If node will get properly linked, it will not through any error, and will print node version. You can read nice explanation about it from [here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/01/warning-node-already-installed-its-just.html).

Answer (score 0):

For line did the job:

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

It forces the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

Answer (score -2):

You can change the permission of the file `"/usr/local/bin/node"`, like `"chmod +w /usr/local/bin/node"`, to make it writable.