# How to update npm to the latest version when custom global directory is set

Tags: node.js, npm, path, package-managers

Updating `npm` the usual way with

`npm i npm@latest -g`

leads to the latest version of `npm` installed in my custom directory `.npm-global/` set via

```
prefix=${HOME}/.npm-global
```

in my `.npmrc`.
 However the old version `/usr/local/bin/npm` takes precendence.  Attempting to naively link leads to error:

○ → link  ~/.npm-global/bin/npm npm

dhcp-160 in /usr/local/bin
○ → npm
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at /usr/local/bin/npm:19:21
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/npm:79:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

So how can I switch to the new `npm` version?

Comment: Solved by this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/265536/56300

Answer (score 2):

Execute below commands in the same order:

```
sudo brew uninstall node
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew install node
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
brew link --overwrite node
brew post install node
```

**Reference Page:** [Node.js not linked error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663488/node-js-not-linked-error)

Comment: I did not use brew to install node, and I would rather not uninstall it.

Comment: You have mistake in command brew `post install node`
Here is correct command: `brew postinstall node`