# Unable to link/run Node.js v6 in Homebrew

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I'm trying to specifically install Node.js v6, which is proving confusingly difficult.

On a new MacBook running Sierra, I've run:
`brew install node@6`

This gave me:

```
Please note by default only English locale support is provided. If you need
full locale support you should either rebuild with full icu:
  `brew reinstall node --with-full-icu`
or add full icu data at runtime following:
  https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Intl#using-and-customizing-the-small-icu-build

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

This is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/node@6/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/node@6/include


Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node@6/6.9.5: 3,891 files, 41.3M
```

If I run `which node`, I get `node not found`. If I run `brew link node`, I get `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node`. I also ran `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`.

How can I "link" Node.js v6 so that other software can find it? Do I run `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`? I don't want to run anything I'm not sure of.

Comment: I'd rather use `n`. https://github.com/tj/n

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use Homebrew to install node.

I like the [Node Version Manager (NVM)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), and there is [n](https://github.com/tj/n) (as mentioned by @ntalbs in the comments). These are better options on a Mac for node, to avoid [certain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663488/node-js-not-linked-error). [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056115/how-to-install-latest-version-of-node-using-brew). [later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849741/homebrew-npm-install-could-not-symlink).

Note, you can install `nvm` and `n` via Homebrew. (`brew install nvm` or `brew install n`).

Comment: Yeah, I gave in and used `n`. I was only pursuing Homebrew because it worked on another machine (famous last words). Thanks for the tip