# What would be the way now to install node with npm via brew

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

I've installed node on my macOS

```
brew install node
```

After doing this, node is installed correctly:

```
$ node -v
  v8.4.0
```

But running

```
$ npm -v
```

gives me `-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`

What would be the way now to install node with npm via brew?

`brew install node` uses by default --without-npm

Comment: What does `which -a npm` say? Does it work if you try it in a new terminal session?

Comment: Judging by the amount of issues posted here on SO caused by Homebrew-installs of Node.js, I would suggest using the official Node.js installer for macOS instead.

Comment: @robertklep I'd recommend [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) personally. Used it widely on Mac OS and Linux and never had any problems with it.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I use `nvm` as well, but also have a "global" Node.js installation (and nvm's "default" pointing to it).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I ran `$ brew doctor` to make sure node was linked first. Then I ran 

`$ brew postinstall node`

`$ npm -v` should now show the version number.

Answer (score 1):

I stepped into a similar issue, too. My problem was that I still had not a 
[`~/.bash_profile` file in place](https://gist.github.com/rcugut/c7abd2a425bb65da3c61d8341cd4b02d#and-make-sure-you-load-the-bashrc-in-your-bash_profile) and therefore no place where to actually link my bash command to `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Homebrew to install node.

I like the [Node Version Manager (NVM)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), and there is [n](https://github.com/tj/n). These are better options on a Mac for node, to avoid [certain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663488/node-js-not-linked-error). [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056115/how-to-install-latest-version-of-node-using-brew). [later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849741/homebrew-npm-install-could-not-symlink). Plus it avoids this question, as these node versions include `npm`.

Note, you can install `nvm` and `n` via Homebrew. (`brew install nvm` or `brew install n`).